# How to filter posts in admin by before date or by post status 'future'?

Tags: filters, admin, date, post-status

I have read/searched a ton of questions but all I find seem to be related to custom post types and such.

The situation is that sometimes we happen to have a lot of posts waiting for to be published and I would like to preferably only show posts to a week from now (so all posts before `strtotime("+1 week"))` but if that's not plausable, I would like to filter out all posts by status "future" from the edit.php "all" view.

Can someone help me out?

```
function hide_future_scheduled($wp_query) {
    global $pagenow;
    if ($pagenow == 'edit.php') {
        $wp_query->set(WHAT CAN I PUT IN HERE TO DO THIS);
    }
}
add_filter('parse_query', 'hide_future_scheduled');
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question pretty much got covered in another thread [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/181466/hiding-by-default-specific-post-status-on-backend-list).

In case anyone else need anything like this I ended up using following code to hide all the posts that are over a week in the future.

```
function hide_future_posts($where, $q) {
    if(is_admin() && $q->is_main_query() && !filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'post_status') && ( $screen = get_current_screen() ) instanceof \WP_Screen && 'edit-post' === $screen->id) {
        global $wpdb;

        $where .= sprintf(" AND {$wpdb->posts}.post_date <= ( '%s' )", date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 week')));
    }
    return $where;
}
add_action( 'posts_where', 'hide_future_posts', 10, 2 );
```