# Hiding by default specific post status on backend list?

Tags: posts, admin, list, publish, post-status

I created various custom post status options (like default ones: "published", "draft" and so on) and one of them is "project closed". I need to hide/exclude by default from post list in the backend the posts set under "project closed" post status.

is there a way to this?
thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear what you're looking for here, but you could try to use the  `posts_where` filter:

```
/**
 * Remove posts, with a given status, on the edit.php (post) screen, 
 * when there's no post status filter selected.
 */

add_action( 'posts_where', function( $where, $q )
{
    if(    is_admin()
        && $q->is_main_query()
        && ! filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'post_status' )
        && ( $screen = get_current_screen() ) instanceof \WP_Screen
        && 'edit-post' === $screen->id
    )
    {
        global $wpdb;

        $status_to_exclude = 'project_close';   // Modify this to your needs!

        $where .= sprintf( 
            " AND {$wpdb->posts}.post_status NOT IN ( '%s' ) ", 
            $status_to_exclude 
        );

    }
    return $where;
}, 10, 2 );
```

where you have to modify the `$status_to_exclude` status. Here we target the `edit.php` screen for the `post` post type. We make sure the `post_status` GET filter is not set.

So when you click on the *All Posts* admin menu link in the backend, this filtering is activated.

Hopefully you can adjust this further to your needs.

Comment: mmh... so i'm supposed to change array (123) with the tag id, but i'm not sure what it is. I mean, there're some post status (like "published", "draft" and so on. one of them is "project closed") i have to put "project-closed" into it?

Comment: It's possible to get the tag ID from the tag slug. It's also possible to use the tag slug in the `tax_query` part of the main query. But I just used the static tag ID here for demonstration purpose. You can also find the tag ID by hand, for example in the url (i.e. the `tag_ID` part) when you edit the corresponding tag. @DanieleChianucci

Comment: hmm, so you want to filter by `post_status` and not by a given tag? I thought you meant the latter case, since you wrote: _tagged as "project closed"_ @DanieleChianucci

Comment: yes! i meant to filter by post status, not by tag. i'm sorry i wrote badly. and sorry for my english. i just want to hide posts under a specific post status from the list!

Comment: I updated the answer. Please edit your question with this extra info. @DanieleChianucci

Comment: you're welcome and thanks for updating your quesiton  @DanieleChianucci